# Respond to search query get request

Tags: search, get

When you search for a query at for example Google, or amazon. It sends a get request to the server and comes back with some result. I was wondering how they send that result back. Do they construct a new html file for the query, seems ineffective. Do they respond with a html file and then make a post request back to the server to get the search result. Do they just inject all the information into a html file? None of these really seem correct to me, have been searching but couldnt find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: You can Google for "How the web works".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer a long time ago, if anyone comes across this and wonders heres what i found out:

If you want to add some dynamic html into a webpage, from the server not from the javascript. You have to use templates.

A template/template language makes you able to inject dynamic html, for example search results, into the template and send that as an html file to the request.

For example, if you are using node.js as your server language you could use jade to accomplish this.